# Are Hamiltonian trajectories geodesics on the cotangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry, hamiltonian-path, hamilton-equations

Suppose we have a Hamiltonian dynamics on a phase space, whose base space is also a Riemannian manifold. I was wondering if the Hamiltonian trajectories are whether geodesics or only locally geodesics on the cotangent bundle? Thanks!

Comment: If you don't know anything about the Riemannian metric, there's not much to say. Perhaps if $T^*M$ is Kähler or something like it?

Comment: What do you mean by “locally geodesics”? Being a geodesic is a local concept to begin with (related to the global concept of shortest curve between two points, but not the same thing). Hamilton's equations for $H=\frac12 g^{ij} p_i p_j$ are equivalent to the usual second order ODEs for geodesics, so you can say exactly the same thing from the Hamiltonian formulation as from the usual one.

Comment: @IvoTerek Suppose $T^*M$ is a K\"ahler manifold. Would it make any difference?

Comment: @HansLundmark That is absolutely true, provided that the Hamiltonian is $H = \frac{1}{2}g^{ij}p_1p_j$, as you said, but what if the Hamiltonian is $H = \frac{1}{2}g^{ij}p_1p_j + V(\mathbf{x})$? Then, are the Hamiltonian trajectories geodesics, in the sense of being the shortest path between two arbitrary points on the cotangent bundle?

Comment: Certainly not! Just think of the flat (Euclidean) case: trajectories of $H=\tfrac12 (p_1^2+p_2^2)+V(q_1,q_2)$ are usually not straight lines, right?

Answer (score -1):

A short answer is yes, but we need some more restriction on the Hamiltonian we are choosing.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_as_Hamiltonian_flows .